# Get an option from a form to use in a method within the forms model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

I have a form that ask the user to select an option from a list.

After they choose their options then the model should calculate their total bill.

I have an after_save method that runs to calculate the total but it has to know which option the user selected from the form. I need a way to get that one option before the method runs so that it can be accurate. I tried to use an around_save but could not find documentation on how to properly implement. Here is my code as it stands now.

In my model...

```
class Upsell
  include Mongoid::Document

field :user_report_request_type
field :total_cost
...

around_save :total_fees

  private

  def total_fees
      self.total_cost = 0
      self.user_report_request_type
  yield
    items = []
      if user.reportapprovals.empty?
        items << (self.user_report_request_type).to_i
      else
        items << (user.reportapprovals.first.manager_request_report_type).to_i
      end
        ...
    self.total_cost = items.inject(:+)
  end
```

After this it should save the total. But I cant get it to update the total_cost field after this form is resubmitted on an update.

Comment: Can you try using 'puts' or throwing an exception with the contents of total_cost so you can make sure that it is getting the proper value sent into it?

Comment: I just raised an exception right before the last step of the method and it came up so I am not sure why it wont update the total_cost field. Is that what u mean?

Comment: I edited the method by making it an around_save callback and I made the total_cost field zero out and told the method to save the form item user_report_request_type. But it still isnt updating the total_cost field

Comment: you should do this in a before_save

Comment: I got it! I have to do a before_save and before_update. It wasnt running the method before the update only on the inital save. FIXED IT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! I have to do a before_save and before_update. It wasn't running the method before the update only on the initial save. It needs to run on updates and the initial save to work properly.

```
before_save :total_fees
before_update :total_fees
```